# Rewrite URL with htaccess to accept trailing slash or not

Tags: .htaccess

I have url like:

```
localhost/tekcreditunion/who-we-are
```

How do I make htaccess understand that

```
localhost/tekcreditunion/who-we-are/
```

Is still the same file or page? I just want the server to return to the same page if trailing slash is added or not

How do i do this in htaccess ?

```
RewriteRule ^who-we-are$ who-we-are.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^who-we-are([^/]+)?$ who-we-are.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^who-we-are/([^/.]+)/?$ who-we-are.php?category=$1& [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?tekcreditunion/who-we-are/?$ /tekcreditunion/who-we-are.php [END]
```

And here the general version:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?tekcreditunion/([^/]+)/?$ /tekcreditunion/$1.php [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).